# Sync a git repository between two local devices without internet connection

Tags: git, ssh

I have a repository `repo` on github and I have its clone on my local system (`mac`) which I use to make edits and push on daily basis; `mac` has an internet connection for doing this.

But the project is deployed on a NVIDIA Jetson device `jetson` which does not have access to an internet connection at all times. (This is because I have disabled dhcp to provide a static IP to its `eth0` interface.) For deployment and testing, I use various `ssh` tools to migrate the code from `mac` to `jetson`.

How can I sync the repository on `mac` and `jetson` which only communicate via `ssh` ?

Comment: Git has `git bundle` for this sort of thing. It's a bit klunky and manual but you should be able to do everything you need with that plus `scp`.

Comment: You could also look into just using [`rsync`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories) to copy over the files

Comment: Is git itself available on `jetson`?

Comment: @stdtom yes git is available.

Comment: @PeDro Do you need the full history of the repository on jetson, or just the files of the current HEAD?

Comment: @VonC I try to take backups periodically from `jetson` -> `mac` -> github. So yeah current HEAD

Comment: @PeDro OK. That is what `git archive is for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `git` available on jetson and if `git push jetson master` looks like a desirable way to push the repo to the jetson device, you could use server-side git hooks.

This proposal assumes that you want to edit the repo on `mac` and want to push changes to `jetson` for deployment. We will assume that you want to deploy the master branch of your repo to `/home/user/project/deploydir` on jetson.
To achieve this, create `deploydir`as well as a bare git repo on `jetson`:

```
# create the remote deploydir
mkdir -p /home/user/project/deploydir

# create the remote repo
git -C /home/user/project init --bare repo
```

Next you need to setup the server-side git hook on `jetson`:

```
touch /home/user/project/repo/hooks/post-receive
chmod +x /home/user/project/repo/hooks/post-receive
nano /home/user/project/repo/hooks/post-receive
```

Paste the following into the `post-receive` hook script in nano. Basically, this will make sure that if you push a new `master` ref to the repo, it will be checked out to the `deploydir`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
  if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
  then
    echo "Master ref received. Updating local work-dir ..."
    git --work-tree=/home/user/project/deploydir --git-dir=/home/user/project/repo checkout -f
  else
    echo "Ref $ref successfully received; Not in master branch, so nothing to do."
  fi
done
```

Afterwards on `mac`:

```
# Add the remote to the git repo:
git remote add jetson user@hostname:/home/user/project/repo/

# Push the master branch to jetson
git push jetson master

# Push the master branch to origin
git push origin master
```

The last statement assumes you have already a remote `origin` defined in your repo which points to your Github repo.

#### Update:

Update, as you pointed out in the comments, that there will be code changes on`jetson`:
In this case you can clone the repo on jetson to a local workdir on jetson:

```
cd /home/user/project
git clone /home/user/project/repo /home/user/project/workdir
```

Now, you have a local workdir on `jetson` in which you can make code changes and push/fetch/pull to the bare repo.
You can sync your code changes between the workdirs on `mac` and `jetson` by pushing/fetching/pulling between these workdirs and the bare repo on `jetson`. However, a sync between these two workdirs requires a command to be executed on both machines.

Every push to the master branch will be instantly checked out to `deploydir` on `jetson`, which might be useful to deploy changes to the location from where the code will be executed.

Comment: So I have 2 instances of the upstreams/remote repo now: on `jetson` and github. Right ? Can I freely pull and push to either using `git remote set-url xyz` and `git pull` ?

Comment: Does the `workdir` serve any important purpose here ?

Comment: @PeDro I updated my answer. `workdir` will be the path to which the repo will be checked out on `jetson`. Yes, you should be able to pull and push to/from both remote repos.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I understand that the `bare` git initiation doesn't allow me to make changes and commit in `jetson`. But I need this to happen so I can pull changes from `jetson` to `mac`. Should I initiate the `jetson` repo as normal repository with a work tree ?

Comment: @PeDro git won't allow you to push to a non-bare repo by default, as this will lead to inconsistencies between index and work tree. You can allow this in the git config but it is strongly discouraged. I updated the answer with a section on how to create a separate workdir on the same machine as the bare repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the full history of the repository on the destination side, you might consider [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) instead of [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle).

That way, you have only one file (an archive) to `rsync` or `scp` over, and then uncompress.

Comment: I need to merge the code from `jetson` to my `mac` without the need to tar and untar it everyday.

Comment: @PeDro That means a repository on `jetson` side (stdtom's answer) and a `git pull` from mac side.

Comment: @PeDro Does this mean, code will also be changed on `jetson`? This is a requirement which is not taken into account in my answer yet.

Comment: @stdtom yes, there will be changes on `jetson`'s version of repo too